# how to group items using array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to take single denominational array and group the items in a multi-denominational array.

Here is what I did

```js
$(function(){
    
 // this array should be groupped by group value "if one exists." In this case, it should be 2 groups
 // (group_1 and group_2)
    var items = [
        {
            group: "group_1",
            text: "Text 1",
            value: "1",
        },      
        {
            group: "group_2",
            text: "Text 1",
            value: "21",
        },
        {
            group: "group_1",
            text: "Text 2",
            value: "2",
        },
        {
            group: "group_1",
            text: "Text 3",
            value: "3",
        },
        {
            text: "Text 30",
            value: "30",
        }
    ];


    var groups = [];

    $.each(items, function(i, item){

        if( typeof item.group === 'undefined'){
            return; // continue, ignore any item that does not have a group name
        }
    
    if( !(item.group in groups)) {
          // create a new group in the array
            groups[item.group] = [];
    }
        // push item to the group
        groups[item.group].push({text: item.text, value: item.value});

    });

    $('#console').text('Expecting the length to be 2 groups but getting ' + groups.length);
  console.log(groups);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="console">
</div>
```

I am expecting the length of the `groups` array to be 2 since there is `group_1` and `group_2`. However, I am getting array with 0 length.

How can I correctly group these items by the value of the `group` property?

Comment: The main issue with your current attempt is that you use an array (`groups = []`) while using `"group_1"` to access each group. Those are not indexes, but keys. Using an object would solve the majority of the problem. This means replacing `groups = []` with `groups = {}`. (keep in mind an object does not have a `length` property.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like that ?

see [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const items = 
  [ { group: "group_1", text: "Text 1",  value: "1"  } 
  , { group: "group_2", text: "Text 1",  value: "21" } 
  , { group: "group_1", text: "Text 2",  value: "2"  } 
  , { group: "group_1", text: "Text 3",  value: "3"  } 
  , {                   text: "Text 30", value: "30" } 
  ] 

const groups = items.reduce((r,{group,...other})=>
  {
  if (!group) return r
  let grp = r.find(x=>x.some(z=>z.group===group))
  if (!grp) r.push([{group,...other}])
  else grp.push( {group,...other} )
  return r
  }
  ,[])

console.log( groups )
```

Or:

```js
const items = 
  [ { group: "group_1", text: "Text 1",  value: "1"  } 
  , { group: "group_2", text: "Text 1",  value: "21" } 
  , { group: "group_1", text: "Text 2",  value: "2"  } 
  , { group: "group_1", text: "Text 3",  value: "3"  } 
  , {                   text: "Text 30", value: "30" } 
  ] 
       
const groups = items.reduce((r, { group, ...other})=>
  {
  if (!group) return r
  let grp = r.find(x=>x.group===group)
  if (!grp) 
    {
    grp = { group, elements:[] }
    r.push(grp)
    }
  grp.elements.push({...other})
  return r
  }
  ,[]);

console.log(  groups )
```